# Are association rewards exempt from the daily reputation soft cap?

Tags: support, reputation, linked-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I recently achieved 200 reputation of Stack Overflow (deposit congratulations to the left) and I got a +100 rep association bonus because of my linked account here. Does this +100 count towards my reputation soft cap for the day?

Comment: Not according to http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/134175

Comment: That mentions accepted answers and bounties, but this is a bonus for having more than one account.

Comment: "You can earn a maximum of +200 reputation from upvotes and suggested edits in any given day"

Comment: Thank you. Post this as an answer so I may accept it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, bonuses are not counted in any sort of reputation cap. They also do not count towards the Mortarboard-class badges where you need to achieve 200 reputation in a single day (whereas accepted answers and bounties do).